# onActivityResult is returning NullPointerException when called startActivityForResult to capture image

Tags: android, android-intent

I am calling camera application with `startActivityForResult`  and passing image URI by myself. but after image captured then I receive `NullpointerException` in `onActivityResult`.

The stack generated is:

```
E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.fieldexecutive/com.example.fieldexecutive.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException    
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2997)    
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2445)    
E AndroidRuntime:   ... 13 more    
E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException    
E AndroidRuntime:   at com.example.fieldexecutive.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:152)    
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4654)    
E AndroidRuntime:   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2993)    
E AndroidRuntime:   ... 14 more
```

In my `onActivityResult` I am not even using the returned data, instead I am using the passed URI by me.  Also the image is saved at the passed URI but data is returned as `null`.

This problem occurs sometimes. around once in five times I run my application.

Here is the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri); 
this.startActivityForResult(intent, RES_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CHEAQUE);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

     switch (requestCode) { 

            case RES_IMAGE_CAPTURE_CHEAQUE: 

                Log.e( TAG, "resultCode: " + resultCode );

                switch( resultCode )
                {
                    case 0:
                        Log.e( TAG, "in onActivityResult : image cancelled" );
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        //image storead, now load it in the web
                        Intent i=new Intent(this,CheaqueActivity.class);

                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                    }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: MainActivity.java:152  which line is it in your code

Comment: have you added permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>` ?